# What websites can I use to sort my unlisted followers, into a new Twitter list?

Tags: twitter

Does it exist online already, or do I have to make it myself?

Comment: The best one I've found is Icotile. https://icotile.ogaoga.org/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tried http://twitlistmanager.com/ which does this job perfectly fine for me.

Comment: How does that service work to solve the OP's problem?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As @VidarS.Ramdal has kindly pointed out, please summarize why this fulfills the OP's requirements. Thanks!